# python pip install fails

Tags: python, module, pip, installation

I'm trying to install pyautogui with pip but I get a fail whenever i try.

```
Collecting pyautogui
  Using cached PyAutoGUI-0.9.36.tar.gz
[31mException:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Lewis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Users\Lewis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 335, in run
    wb.build(autobuilding=True)
  File "C:\Users\Lewis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 749, in build
    self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)
  File "C:\Users\Lewis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "C:\Users\Lewis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 634, in _prepare_file
    abstract_dist.prep_for_dist()
  File "C:\Users\Lewis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 129, in prep_for_dist
    self.req_to_install.run_egg_info()
  File "C:\Users\Lewis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 439, in run_egg_info
    command_desc='python setup.py egg_info')
  File "C:\Users\Lewis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\__init__.py", line 676, in call_subprocess
    line = console_to_str(proc.stdout.readline())
  File "C:\Users\Lewis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\compat\__init__.py", line 73, in console_to_str
    return s.decode(sys.__stdout__.encoding)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'encoding'[0m
>>>
```

The code I used to start the download was

```
import pip
pip.main(['install', "pyautogui"])
```

Comment: I would recommend installing from the command line rather than from a script

Comment: Why didn't you run `pip` (or `pip3`) from the command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pip` is meant to be run as a command from the command line.

Open a terminal, and run:

```
pip install pyautogui
```

If you're using Linux, just open a terminal.
If you're using Windows, hit <kbd>windows</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>, and search `cmd`, or right-click on the start menu and look for `Open a terminal` or something like this.

You might need to run the command with elevated privileges (`sudo` on Linux, `Open a terminal (admin)` on Windows).

Comment: Thanks, it turns out that i had to edit the environment path settings or something. (I don't quite remember anymore)